# My goal is to extract data from a websites HTML and store it with rest of my data points

Tags: python, database, web-scraping

I have identified a key indicator in the HTLM code i need to extract and use as a variable. however i am very new (1 month old) to programing and do not know the techniques yet.

[image]
^^^^ is the HTLM code i need to extract

[image]

^^^^ is were i would like to inport it

```
` def ClientInformation():
CI = textbox.get('1.0', END)
#Split Client Information by " : "
CIS = re.split(r' ', str(CI))

FN = CIS[0]
LN = CIS[1]
CT = CIS[2]
ST = CIS[3]
options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


#Installs and Opens Chrome to your clients True People Search reslutes
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
                      options=options)
driver.get("https://www.truepeoplesearch.com/results?name=" + FN + "%20" + LN +"&citystatezip= " + CT + " %20" + ST + "")

time.sleep(.05)
`
```

after time.sleep is were i will be adding the new bit after i figure out how to extract the variable from the HTML.

[image]
I will need to grab the telephone number and "smaller" after navigating to the correct page through the above code, that information might not always be there and if it is not i would like to export N/A